# Complex Analysis Integration Checking?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was wondering if anyone can check my integration. I evaluated this $\int_{|z|=3} \! \frac{dz}{z^{2}(z-4)^{2}} \,$ to be zero but then when I checked it by using another integration method, I got a different answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) with $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z - 4)^2}$ and then your integral is precisely given by the formula

$$f'(0) = \frac{1!}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z| = 3} \frac{f(z)}{(z - 0)^{1 + 1}} \mathrm{d}z = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z| = 3} \frac{f(z)}{z^2}  \mathrm{d}z$$

Then since $$f'(z) = \frac{-2}{(z - 4)^3}$$ you get

$$\int_{|z|=3} \! \frac{dz}{z^{2}(z-4)^{2}}  = 2 \pi i f'(0) = \frac{ \pi i}{16} $$

so you don't get $0$ for an answer.

Note in particular that the function $f(z)$ is holomorphic inside the closed disk $|z| = 3$ because it only has a double pole at $z = 4$, which is outside that disk.

Comment: I used that formula but then I assumed that the poles were inside the disk $|z|=3$ which is a circle of the form $x^2 + y^2 = 9$. Thanks for additional confirmation.

Comment: @CalculusStudent I'm glad that it helped you. Now, remember that you can accept answers by clicking on the check mark that's below the upvote/downvote arrows next to an answer. I see that you have a few questions which have been answered but you haven't accepted any answers yet, and since you are a new user you may not even be aware that it is possible and actually encouraged to accept an answer once you feel that your question has been successfully answered.

Comment: I didn't know that sorry, lol.